# check all radio list radio button has been selected or not on gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have design one form of review while saving this form i have to check whether all radio list radio button has been selected or not i also wrote javascript but  it is not giving desire output so please help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var validateradios = function () {

        var icount = 0;
        var grid = document.getElementById('<%=gvQuestion.ClientID %>');
        alert(grid.rows.length);
        for (var i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = grid.rows[i];
            var targetcell = row.cells[2];
            var inputs = targetcell.getElementsByTagName("input");
            alert(inputs.length);
            for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++)

                if (inputs[0].checked) {
                    icount++; break;
                }


        }

        if (icount == (grid.rows.length - 1))
            alert(' all rows checked');
        else
            alert('some rows need to be checked');

    }
</script>

        ////Gridview code
           <asp:GridView ID="gvQuestion" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="data-grid">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Questions">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblQuestions" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Questions")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Opinion">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="150px" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioButtonOpinion" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" AutoPostBack="false">
                            <%-- OnSelectedIndexChanged="radioButtonGender_SelectedIndexChanged"--%>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Strongly Disagree"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Disagree"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Neutral"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Agree"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="Strongly Agree"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="s"
                            ControlToValidate="radioButtonOpinion" ErrorMessage="*Please select"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Are you against using server side code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working because i have missed opening and closing curly bracket after for

(var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var validateradios = function () {
        var icount = 0;
        var grid = document.getElementById('<%=gvQuestion.ClientID %>');
        alert(grid.rows.length);
        for (var i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = grid.rows[i];
            var targetcell = row.cells[2];
            var inputs = targetcell.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                if (inputs[j].checked) {
                    icount++; break;  
                }
            }
        }
        alert(icount)
        if (icount == (grid.rows.length - 1))
            alert(' all rows checked');
        else
            alert('some rows need to be checked');
    }
</script>
```